# python operations without! selecting objects and entering edit mode

Tags: python, animation-nodes

Is it possible to make some operatoins on curve without entering edit mode?

I am using small code in Animation Nodes:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') 
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
obj.select = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
obj.data.splines.remove(obj.data.splines[0])
```

I am using many small scripts in Animation Nodes, and each time i have to take care if object is selected and context is correct.

Is it possible to use .remove without all previous lines?
like this:`remove(obj, splines)`

Comment: What is the need to bpy.ops.xxx and not simply use remove? Is there something due to AN in that?

Comment: I don't know. 
remove(obj.data.splines[0])  
AN says "name 'remove' is not defined"

Comment: But obj.data.splines.remove(obj.data.splines[0]) should work without using bpy.ops before. You should provide more details about your node setting and the way the parameters are given to it